# How do I continue to next 'if' statement if first 'if' returns false?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

In Windows batch file:

```
if something==something (
  run cmd
) else (
  if returned false, what do I put in here to continue to next 'if'?
)

if something2==something2 (
 etc etc.
)
```

If first statement returned false, it goes to `else`, what do I put inside `else` to continue to next `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? Just put the next statement after the first if block closes. Am I missing something?

```
if something==something (
  run cmd
)

if something2==something2 (
 etc etc.
)
```

Comment: I thought it doesn't work like that and every 'if' needs an 'else'.

Comment: An `else` case is not a requirement.